# Autostart Android application after installation complete

Tags: android

I know how to autostart after boot with the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent action, but I didn't find how to autostart an application just after it has been installed on the device.

For my application I would like to set an alarm after the install, I looked at the [`PACKAGE_ADDED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) intent action but it says that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.

Any advice ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mention, there's no way of receiving your own `PACKAGE_ADDED` event; you just have to check for a flag each time you start your application.

For example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!prefs.contains(KEY_FIRST_RUN)) {
    /* do some one-off stuff here */
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(KEY_FIRST_RUN, false).commit();
}
```

You could put this in your `Application` class, or in your launcher's `onCreate` method.

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand why I didn't find anything about that !
What I would like is that to set the alarm without starting my application, but I think it's not possible...


So there is no way to auto-launch an application apart after boot...

Comment: "So there is no way to auto-launch an application apart after boot" -- correct. That is by design.

Comment: thanks all, I consider Christopher's response as an acceptable answer so ;-)

Comment: Indeed, it is by design, not that I quite agree with the decision.  
If developers are trusted not to abuse the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, why not the `PACKAGE_ADDED` one?

Comment: Especially that a `PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast is triggered at each install of any application...