# How to send mail at the time of installing the app?

Tags: android, email

In my android application i want to send mail from my application at the time of installing the application
I want to know it is possible to send a mail at the time of installing the app

Possible means please help me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer: [Autostart Android application after installation complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975521/autostart-android-application-after-installation-complete)

This seems to be the only way to do it: i.e. check first run. There is no way to hook the event before your app is run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any hooks while its installing. You could have a setting to say "first launch" and send the email on the first launch.