# Auto Launch App when Installed

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which i want to auto launch the application once it is installed from the Google Play Store.I have searched a bit for this, and found threads and answers indicating this cannot be done.
But i also found an app on Play store,[Auto Launch when Installed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.stachibana.AutoLaunch&hl=en&rdid=biz.stachibana.AutoLaunch&rdot=1) which does this very effectively.
Can any one suggest me a logic behind this. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It launches other apps automatically after they are installed  not itself, right ??

Comment: Refer to this links. It might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975521/autostart-android-application-after-installation-complete

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127044/how-to-start-android-service-on-installation

Comment: You cannot launch your own application as you want , the application you mentioned may be using this  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a BroadcastReceiver that is bound to the 
BOOT_COMPLETED action.

**Example**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     package="com.alfray.timeriffic" ...> 
     <application ...> 
      <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
      </receiver> 
  </application> 

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
   </manifest>
```

**It may work. Just try out**

Comment: Yes, but for this method to work the phone has to be booted once right?

Comment: This method only work for android versions prior to 3.1. Now android requires the application to have been started at least once before it will start receiving any intents.