# Autoshow MainActivity after install

Tags: android, android-activity, autostart

I have a question, is it possible to show MainActivity to user after they install my .apk on their devices?
Because I have read that we can't autolaunch our apk after install, but I just need to show my Activity, so is it possible?

Comment: Thanks Google, it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't auto run your Android application right after the installation.**

Maximum that you can do is to listen to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent, and it will work only if the user manually launch your application at least once.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, you can start a services after installation but no to launch the app. Look this answare to learn more about the problem:

[Autostart android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975521/autostart-android-application-after-installation-complete)
And this
[Launch services after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time/8535062#8535062)