# Android restart apk after installed programmatically

Tags: android, installation, apk, restart, android-install-apk

I've completed a class to download the new version of an apk and install it programmatically using the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"  + ApkName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

It works, it installs the new apk (previously downloaded on SD) but then the app is not restarted but closed.

**There is a way to have it restarted after the installation of the new version?**

Thanks!

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911412/autoshow-mainactivity-after-install/17911519#17911519

Comment: So is it correct that after installing the new version the app exits with no message to the user (something like 'installation succesful')?

Comment: When you re-installing APK, it kill's the previous running processes related to the old version before installing the new APK.